# Facebook shows login dialog instead of app request dialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

In my app i need to present Facebook AppRequest dialogue to user. I do it like this:

```
 NSMutableDictionary* params =
[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:friendId forKey:@"to"];

[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:FBSession.activeSession
                                              message:NSLocalizedString(@"AppRequestMessage", "")
                                                title:NSLocalizedString(@"AppRequestTitle", "")
                                           parameters:params
                                              handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *url, NSError *error){

                                                  if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted)
                                                  {
                                                      if (error)
                                                      [FRBaseViewController showAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"AppRequestFail", "") message:error.localizedDescription];
                                                  }
                                                  else
                                                  {
                                                      if ([url.description rangeOfString:@"error"].location == NSNotFound)
                                                      {
                                                          if ([FRDataModel sharedInstance].shouldChallenge)
                                                              [[FRDataModel sharedInstance] finishedRatingFriend];
                                                      }
                                                  }

                                                  FRAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
                                                  FRNavigationController *navController = (FRNavigationController *)delegate.navigationController;
                                                  [(FRNavigationController *)navController pseudoPopToFrindViewController];
                                              }];
```

and most part of the time it works all right. But sometimes, when long time has passed since user logged in into the app it shows not AppRequest dialog, but Login dialog. As soon as user logs out and logs in again it then works all right again. I think at some point Facebook SDK starts to think that user is not logged in (despite the user definitely IS logged in) or something like this. Have you ever seen such a behaviour? Can you please suggest me something? Thanks

Comment: Andre, do you check, if session is opened before sending this request? Also, you must handle session state changes somewhere, because it can expire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I found the solution. The reason for such a behaviour was that some cookies needed for correct Facebook work was missing. I don't know why they disappear sometimes from `NSHTTPCookieStorage` but just knowing that they do helped me a lot. What I did is I provided another storage for cookies. Now I update the storage every time the cookies are updated. Then I check if `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]` contains the needed cookies (they names are `c_user` and `xs`). If it doesn't I take those cookie from my storage and add them to `[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage]`. And it works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the sessions that are being created, what I mean is check [FBSession activeSession]. It could be that when your user logs in they have a session and that stays open for as long as they use the app. Once they close it and revisit your app their sessions could have been closed, thus forcing them to login again?

What have you tried? I have played with the FBSDK a lot so let me know what you have tried/your situation in more detail and I can see what differences there are to my implementation.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

That's how I open a Facebook session, by doing so it attempts a Facebook Login, prefering system account and falling back to fast app switch if necessary. WebView is definitely last resort.

```
// Initialize a session object
FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] init];

// Set the active session
[FBSession setActiveSession:session];

// Open the session
[session openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
        completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                            FBSessionState status,
                            NSError *error) {

    // You're good to go
    //
    if (!error && FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {

        // Retrieve Token
        //
        FBAccessTokenData *data = [FBSession.activeSession accessTokenData];
        NSString *accessToken = data.accessToken;

        if ([FRDataModel sharedInstance].shouldChallenge)
            [[FRDataModel sharedInstance] finishedRatingFriend];
    }
    else {
        [FRBaseViewController showAlertWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"AppRequestFail", "") message:error.localizedDescription];
    }

    FRAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    FRNavigationController *navController = (FRNavigationController *)delegate.navigationController;
    [(FRNavigationController *)navController pseudoPopToFrindViewController];
}];
```

Official documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/).